# Adding p-values in tbl summary

Tags: r, gtsummary

I am trying to build on the guidance provided here: [Tests/methods available in add_p() and add_difference()][1] specifically under the section "Custom Functions"
by passing a customized function in `add_p()` function. My goal is to have the p-values from an ANOVA test while incorporating survey design effect. The code am using is

```
rm(list = ls())

library(gtsummary)
library(dplyr)
library(srvyr)
library(survey)


data <- structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25), 
                       strata = c(10, 20, 30, 10, 20, 20, 10, 20, 30, 30, 10, 30, 30, 20, 10, 20, 20, 20, 10, 20, 20, 30, 30, 20, 30), 
                       weight = c(10, 8, 17, 15, 9, 10, 25, 8, 8, 13, 17, 24, 12, 15, 3, 12, 16, 17, 24, 12, 3, 2, 8, 14, 4), 
                       popgroup = c("A", "B", "A", "C", "A", "C", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "C", "A", "B", "A", "C", "B", "A", "C", "B", "A", "B", "C", "B", "B"),
                       gender = c("Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male"),
                       inc_01 = c(1500, 1200, 130, 500, 750, 2000, 10000, 1500, 1050, 400, 360, 490, 250, 400, 2500, 1300, 800, 540, 690, 520, 600, 700, 700, 600, 400), 
                       inc_02 = c(360, 450, 120, 300, 900, 560, 450, 280, 720, 360, 1000, 900, 530, 820, 640, 520, 130, 140, 150, 650, 240, 130, 200, 300, 500)), 
                  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -25L))


dclus2 <- survey::svydesign(
            id = ~ id,
            strata = ~ strata,
            weights = ~ weight,
            data = data
          )


ttest_common_variance <- function(data, variable = inc_01, by = popgroup, ...) {
                                  model<-svyglm(variable ~ by, design=dclus2)
                                  reg_v <- regTermTest(model,~ by)
                                  reg_v1 <- as.numeric(reg_v$p)
                                  reg_v2 <- tibble( p.value = reg_v1 )
}


tbl_2 <-data |>
  as_survey_design(strata = strata, weights = weight) %>%
  gtsummary::tbl_svysummary(
    by = popgroup,
    type = where(is.numeric) ~ "continuous",
    statistic = list(c(inc_01, inc_02) ~ "{mean} {mean.std.error}"),
    missing = "no",
    digits = list(c(inc_01, inc_02) ~ c(4)),
    include = c(inc_01, inc_02)
  ) |>
  gtsummary::add_p(
    test       = c(inc_01, inc_02) ~ "ttest_common_variance",
    pvalue_fun = function(x) gtsummary::style_pvalue(x, digits = 3)
  ) |>
  as_tibble()
```

but am getting the error

> There was an error in 'add_p()/add_difference()' for variable 'inc_01', p-value omitted:
> Error in svyglm.survey.design(variable ~ by, design = dclus2, family = quasibinomial()): all variables must be in design= argument

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance
[1]: https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/reference/tests.html

Comment: your `ttest_common_variance` function doesn't return anything.

Comment: also have you checked that your models work at all?  i don't know much about the survey packages but it looks like you have a quasibinomial model for a continuous outcome.

Comment: @GeorgeSavva I believe by default it should return the last object. I used quasibinomial model option to suppress the error message but I can do away with it

Comment: No, R does not by default return the last object if it is assigned to something else as in your code.  As written your `ttest_common_variance` doesn't return anything, but that is not the problem that is driving the error.  You should check you understand the `svyglm` modelling.

Comment: @Daniel D. Sjoberg any guidance? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have *several* issues in this code. In the order that errors appear:

> Error in svyglm.survey.design(variable ~ by, design = dclus2): all variables must be in design= argument

This is quite self-explanatory, any variables that go in your model must be in the `svydesign` object.

```r
dclus2 <- survey::svydesign(
  id = ~ id,
  strata = ~ strata,
  weights = ~ weight,
  ## Include variables measured.
  variables = ~ inc_01 + inc_02 + popgroup,
  data = data
)
```

All remaining problems are with your `ttest_common_variance` function:

1. You're passing in `variable` and `by` but these are not existing objects, or rather, you're not actually creating a formula out of them.
2. You're returning a `tibble`, but `gtsummary` expects a scalar. `regTermTest` returns a 1x1 matrix, so we can just take its first element.

Here's a version that should work:

```r
ttest_common_variance <- function(data, variable = "inc_01", by = "popgroup", ...) {
  model <- svyglm(formula(paste0(variable, "~", by)), design=dclus2)
  regTermTest(model, formula(paste0("~", by)))$p[1]
}

... pipeline skipped

#> `**Character**` `**A**, N = 101`  `**B**, N = 112`      `**C**, N = 93`   `**p-value**`
#> <chr>           <chr>             <chr>                 <chr>             <chr>        
#> inc_01          561.9802 137.7631 2,825.3571 1,669.4621 828.1720 169.7938 0.305        
#> inc_02          463.3663 130.1409 459.7321 80.4854      463.8710 143.0381 >0.999
```

Comment: This is super brilliance!!!! Thanks so much for taking time and providing an awesome solution.